# I see ad landing page rendering issues on some devices for my app, mostly on samsung. How should I investigate it?

Tags: android, html, mobile-application

So I have an app wherein ads appear at the bottom of the screen. When the ad is clicked, landing page should open in the device browser. However in some cases, it opens in the bottom area on the app itself (where the ad is shown). Has someone else also faced this issue? How to drill down to the reason? How to fix it?
I tried testing the app on a number of devices and saw the same happening for Micromax as well. The issue was seen on Samsung Galaxy : Android 4.4.2, Kernel version 3.4.0, Chrome 37.0.2062.117; and on Micromax: Android 4.4.2, Kernel version 3.4.67, Chrome 35.0.1916.141
I also tested the landing page url on mobi.ready and it reported some XHTML markup issues. Is that the reason?

Comment: Is this a Chrome App? Or what?

Comment: The browser is Android Chrome browser, there is no specific app it happened on, it was reported on one app and when I built an app to test the issue I could reproduce it.

Comment: We don't call this kind of app as Chrome App.

Comment: neither am I, all I am saying is I expect the ad to render in the default browser of device but it is rendering in the app itself, this happened on clicking ad from 2 apps.